# Set API data to react state without endless rerendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm using the Axios get method to fetch weather data from an API endpoint and set it to the weather useState.

It keeps rerendering the data as can be seen when logging weather to the console which renders endlessly.

How can I set it up so that it only sets the weather state once when needed?

---

**Here is my code:**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import './App.css'

const api_key = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY_WEATHER_API

const App = () => {
  const [countries, setCountries] = useState([])
  const [countrySearch, setCountrySearch] = useState('')
  const [weather, setWeather] = useState(
      {
        current:{
          temp_c:'', 
          condition:{icon: ''},
          wind_mph: '', 
          wind_dir: ''
        }
      }
    )

  const hook = () => {
    axios
      .get('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all')
      .then(response => setCountries(response.data))
  }
  useEffect(hook, [])
  
  const countrySearchHandler = (event) => {
    setCountrySearch(event.target.value)
  }

  const handleShowCountry = (event) => {
    setCountrySearch(event.target.value)
  }

  const limitSearchArray = () => {
    const limitedSearch = countries.filter(country => country.name.toLowerCase()
                                   .indexOf(countrySearch.toLowerCase()) !== -1)

    if (limitedSearch.length === 1) {
      const country = limitedSearch[0]
      axios
      .get(`http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=${api_key}&q=${country.capital}&aqi=no`)
      .then(response => setWeather(response.data))
      console.log(weather)
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>{country.name}</h1>
          <p>capital {country.capital}</p>
          <p>population {country.population}</p>
          <h2>languages</h2>
          <ul>
            {country.languages.map(language => 
              <li key={language.name}>{language.name}</li>)}
          </ul>
          <img src={country.flag} alt={country.name} height='100px'/>
          <h2>Weather in {country.capital}</h2>
              <p>temperature: {weather.current.temp_c} Celcius</p>
              <img src={weather.current.condition.icon} alt={country.capital}/>
              <p>wind: {weather.current.wind_mph} mph direction {weather.current.wind_dir}</p>
        </div>
      )
    } else if (limitedSearch.length <= 10){
        return (
          limitedSearch.map(country => 
          <p key={country.name}>{country.name}
            <button value={country.name} onClick={handleShowCountry}>show</button>
          </p>)
        )
    } else {
        return 'Too many matches, specify another filter'
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      find countries <input value={countrySearch} onChange={countrySearchHandler}></input>
      <div>
        {limitSearchArray()}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `axios` get weather into `useEffect` instead in `limitSearchArray` funtion

```
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(
        `http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=${api_key}&q=${country.capital}&aqi=no`
      )
      .then((response) => setWeather(response.data));
  }, [country]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer but if I do that then `useEffect` has no access to the `country` Array, which is initialized inside of the `limitSearchArray` function, to fire the effect and to use the country data in the url,. Is there a way to get around that?

Comment: Thanks Viet I figured it out. I added country to the Apps state and used an if statement inside the first if condition of the `limitSearchArray` function to check if the current `country` state was equal to `limitedSearch[0]` and if not then set `limitedSearch[0]` as `country` state.

Answer (score 0):

This was the final code that got it to work without continuous rerendering.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect} from 'react'

const api_key = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY_WEATHER_API

const App = () => {
  const [country, setCountry] = useState(
    {
      name: '',
      population: '',
      capital: 'Helsinki',
      languages: [{name:'ENG'}],
      flag: ''
    }
  )
  const [countries, setCountries] = useState([])
  const [countrySearch, setCountrySearch] = useState('')
  const [weather, setWeather] = useState(
      {
        current:{
          temp_c:'', 
          condition:{icon: ''},
          wind_mph: '', 
          wind_dir: ''
        }
      }
    )

  const hook = () => {
    axios
      .get('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all')
      .then(response => setCountries(response.data))
  }
  useEffect(hook, [])
  
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(
        `http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=${api_key}&q=${country.capital}&aqi=no`
      )
      .then((response) => setWeather(response.data));
  }, [country]);
  
  const countrySearchHandler = (event) => {
    setCountrySearch(event.target.value)
  }

  const handleShowCountry = (event) => {
    setCountrySearch(event.target.value)
  }

  const limitSearchArray = () => {
    const limitedSearch = countries.filter(country => country.name.toLowerCase()
                                   .indexOf(countrySearch.toLowerCase()) !== -1)

    if (limitedSearch.length === 1) {
      if(country !== limitedSearch[0]) {
        setCountry(limitedSearch[0])
      }
      console.log(country)
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>{country.name}</h1>
          <p>capital {country.capital}</p>
          <p>population {country.population}</p>
          <h2>languages</h2>
          <ul>
            {country.languages.map(language => 
              <li key={language.name}>{language.name}</li>)}
          </ul>
          <img src={country.flag} alt={country.name} height='100px'/>
          <h2>Weather in {country.capital}</h2>
              <p>temperature: {weather.current.temp_c} Celcius</p>
              <img src={weather.current.condition.icon} alt={country.capital}/>
              <p>wind: {weather.current.wind_mph} mph direction {weather.current.wind_dir}</p>
        </div>
      )
    } else if (limitedSearch.length <= 10){
        return (
          limitedSearch.map(country => 
          <p key={country.name}>{country.name}
            <button value={country.name} onClick={handleShowCountry}>show</button>
          </p>)
        )
    } else {
        return 'Too many matches, specify another filter'
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      find countries <input value={countrySearch} onChange={countrySearchHandler}></input>
      <div>
        {limitSearchArray()}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```